# Terraform Error: vsphere provider doesn’t support resource

Tags: vsphere, terraform

I have a small issue, my terraform code is saying the vsphere provider does not support a vsphere_instance resource.

When I run terraform plan, I get:

```
1 error(s) occurred:

*vsphere_instance.node1: Provider doesn’t support resource: vsphere_instance
```

Terraform template:

```
provider "vsphere" {
    user                 = "andm"
    password             = "Welcome123!"
    vsphere_server       = "vcenter1.domain.com"
    allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

resource "vsphere_instance" "node1" {    
  name        = "node1.domain.com"
  vcpu        = 4
  memory      = 4096
  time_zone   = "040"
  domain      = "hosting.domain.com"
  dns_servers = ["8.8.8.8"]

  disk {
    datastore = "WS006_LUN_197"
    vmdk      = "templates_01/AV_W2K8_Tmlate/AV_W2K8_Template.vmdk"
    type      = "thin"
  }

  network_interface {         
    ipv4_address       = "192.168.0.1"               
    ipv4_gateway       = "192.168.1.1"
    ipv4_prefix_length = "24"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the resource name from `vspher_instance` to `vsphere_virtual_machine`

This should fix your issue.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/index.html

```
VMWARE VSPHERE PROVIDER

RESOURCES
  vsphere_virtual_machine
  vsphere_folder
  vsphere_file
  vsphere_virtual_disk
```